# DPLYR - merging rows together using a column value as a conditional

Tags: r, dplyr, rows

I have a series of rows in a single dataframe.  I'm trying to aggregate the first two rows for each ID- i.e. - I want to combine events 1 and 2 for ID 1 into a single row, events 1 and 2 for ID 2 into a singlw row etc, but leave event 3 completely untouched.

```
id <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5)

event <- c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3)

score <- c(3,NA,1,3,NA,2,6,NA,1,8,NA,2,4,NA,1)

score2 <- c(NA,4,1,NA,5,2,NA,0,3,NA,5,6,NA,8,7)

df <- tibble(id, event, score, score2)
# A tibble: 15 x 4
      id event score score2
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
 1     1     1     3     NA
 2     1     2    NA      4
 3     1     3     1      1
 4     2     1     3     NA
 5     2     2    NA      5
 6     2     3     2      2
 7     3     1     6     NA
 8     3     2    NA      0
 9     3     3     1      3
10     4     1     8     NA
11     4     2    NA      5
12     4     3     2      6
13     5     1     4     NA
14     5     2    NA      8
15     5     3     1      7
```

I've tried :

```
 df_merged<- df %>% group_by (id) %>% summarise_all(funs(min(as.character(.),na.rm=TRUE))),
```

which aggregates these nicely, but then I struggle to merge these back into the orignal dataframe/tibble  (there are really about 300 different "score" columns in the full dataset, so a right_join is a headache with score.x, score.y, score2.x, score2.y all over the place...)

Ideally, the situation would need to be dplyr as the rest of my code runs on this!

EDIT:

Ideally, my expected output would be:

```
# A tibble: 10 x 4
      id event score score2
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
 1     1     1     3      4
 3     1     3     1      1
 4     2     1     3      5
 6     2     3     2      2
 7     3     1     6      0
 9     3     3     1      3
10     4     1     8      5
12     4     3     2      6
13     5     1     4      8
15     5     3     1      7
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We may change the order of `NA` elements with `replace`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    group_by(id) %>%
     mutate(across(starts_with('score'),
         ~replace(., 1:2, .[1:2][order(is.na(.[1:2]))])))  %>% 
    ungroup  %>%   
    filter(if_all(starts_with('score'), Negate(is.na)))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 10 x 4
      id event score score2
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
 1     1     1     3      4
 2     1     3     1      1
 3     2     1     3      5
 4     2     3     2      2
 5     3     1     6      0
 6     3     3     1      3
 7     4     1     8      5
 8     4     3     2      6
 9     5     1     4      8
10     5     3     1      7
```

Comment: Hi, the problem with this method is that this will also coalsece scores where the event is not 1 or 2.  I also don't really want a new variable.

My expected output will be that for ID 1, Events 1 and 2, I'd have a row looking something like this:
 1(ID column)     1(event column)     3(score column)     4(score 2 column)

Comment: Can you please update your post with expeceted output.  From your description it was not clear

Comment: @tomdidiot please check the update

Comment: Hmmm..  I can't seem to get it to work on my larger dataset.  I think I might just need to run this past someone in my lab because the actual dataset is sensitive......

Comment: @tomdidiot when you say you can't get it to work, can you describe the exact problem.  I can think of many issues i..e some 'id' may not have event 1 or 2, or some have only 1 row etc?  Here, I assumed that all 'id' have at least 2 or more rows

Comment: @tomdidiot or another issue is that with `na.omit` at the end.  If you have NA anywhere else other than the 1st 2 rows, that row gets omitted as well.  I can change the code

Comment: @tomdidiot try the update with `filter` and `if_all` instead of `na.omit`

Comment: Hi, thanks - just realised it was the na.omit that was removing most of the rows because I had missing data elsewhere in the row....  It does work, once I fiddled a little with the replace (as I had 3 row to merge together rather than just 2)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative way to achieve your task with `fill` from `tidyr` package:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
    group_by(id) %>%
    fill(everything(), .direction = "down") %>%
    fill(everything(), .direction = "up") %>%
    slice(1,3)
```

```
      id event score score2
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
 1     1     1     3      4
 2     1     3     1      1
 3     2     1     3      5
 4     2     3     2      2
 5     3     1     6      0
 6     3     3     1      3
 7     4     1     8      5
 8     4     3     2      6
 9     5     1     4      8
10     5     3     1      7
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
library(dplyr)

df_e12 <- df %>%
  filter(event %in% c(1, 2)) %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(across(starts_with("score"), ~min(.x, na.rm = TRUE))) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  distinct(id, .keep_all = TRUE)
  
df_e3 <- df %>%
  filter(event == 3)

df <- bind_rows(df_e12, df_e3) %>% 
  arrange(id, event)

df

> df
# A tibble: 10 x 4
      id event score score2
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
 1     1     1     3      4
 2     1     3     1      1
 3     2     1     3      5
 4     2     3     2      2
 5     3     1     6      0
 6     3     3     1      3
 7     4     1     8      5
 8     4     3     2      6
 9     5     1     4      8
10     5     3     1      7
```